# What's the behaviour of setting multiple delegate on the same class Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have a ViewController that has like 5-6 delegates, when I need to initialize the delegate I use the following code:

```
_ExampleModel.delegate = self;
```

And I was wondering, If I need to initialize lot of delegates do I just need to call for example:

```
_ExampleModel.delegate = self;
_ExampleModel2.delegate = self;
_ExampleModel3.delegate = self;
```

Is it wrong?

Because I can't understand what's the behaviour on the class on calling multiple delegates

Comment: No issue. For example, a UIViewController can have 2 UITableView with the UIViewController as it delegate/datasource.

Comment: if necessary you can do it, organise the group of callback methods, like in case of `UITableView`, there is a delegate for handling the user interactions, and another one to present the data. if it makes sense to isolate different groups of methods, that is obviously something you want to do.

Comment: if you need multiple delegates, it is considerable to use notification instead, it depends on whether the one-way communication would be good enough for your delegates and you don't want to get back anything from them. if yes and you don't expect anything back, then your view controller should broadcast itself only.

Comment: You left out some important details in your question. Are `_ExampleModel1`, `_ExampleModel2`, and `_ExampleModel3` all of the same type or different types? Either way you are fine but the details are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the delegate protocol is defined correctly, each delegate method receives the delegated object, so you can perform educated choices.

For example,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

If you have three table views with the same data source (or delegate), you would know which one you are servicing from the `tableView` variable.

Problem arises when a badly designed delegation protocol is used, usually by lazy or uneducated developers.

```
- (void)didOpen
```

Such a method would be difficult (maybe even impossible) to service multiple delegated objects.

Comment: Yes this is right, basically no problem. However if i saw code like this I would certainly be wondering if blocks or notifications were more suitable for the job.

Comment: @dorada I may be inclined to agree, as multiple handle objects usually leads to some mess. But changing the design is not always possible. If the API provides only delegation, notifications and blocks will not help.